# first data is missing in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i am trying to get data from db, but in while loop, first data is coming blank, let me show you

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `artists` WHERE label_id = '$id' ORDER BY name";

$result = mysql_query($query);



while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

    <option value="<?php echo $info['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $info['name']; ?></option>

   <?php 
        }
 ?>
```

here first $info['ID'] data of the row is missing,  $info['name'] is ok but ID is missing.

where am i wrong you think ?

thx

Comment: Could you post the $mysql_query() statement too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value keys (if it's not $info['id'] for example).

If it's still not working add after the while this row

```
print_r($info); die();
```

In this mode you will see what $info contains (if there is no id, check the query).

Comment: i am getting the selectbox value with this "var aid = $("#artist").val();" maybe this cause that ?

Comment: You may try $('#artist:selected').val() or $('#artist:selected').text()

Answer (score 0):

Your ID field is really called label_id.  Try:

```
<?php echo $info['label_id']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the value="x" is missing , the feeling i am getting is that there is something wrong with ur javascript and its not getting the value from the selectbox and based on that you think that the value is missing .. can u view the html source of the output and view in that if the options actually have the value in them .. also posting ur table schema will be helpful.